# Remove method in double linked list isn't working?

Tags: java, list

would anybody be able to help me with this problem I've been having? I'm trying to implement a doubly linked list for the first time and have been frustrated trying to get my code to work for my remove class:

```
public void remove(int data) {
    if(length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (head.data == data){
        head = head.next;
        length--;
    }
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        if(current.data != data) {
            current = current.next;
            length--;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

I know this question may have been asked before, but I was unable to understand the differences in other people's code as it was much more complex. It's been a really difficult day trying to get this one method working without getting a NullPointerException and help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: where do u get a NPE?

Comment: The last line: current = current.next

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove a single node or part of the front list?
If you are trying to remove a single node, your `current` node is used as a pointer to find the node to be removed, when you find such node, you can change the node's value, if this is the last element, you can set the previous node's next node to null, else set the previous nodes' next node to the node's next node, and change the node's next node's previous node to the node's previous node.

```
 public void remove(int data) {
    if(length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (head.data == data){
        head = head.next;
        length--;
    }
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.data != data) {
            current = current.next;
        } else {
            if (current.next == null) {
                current.pre.next = null;
            } else {
                current.pre.next = current.next;
                current.next.pre = current.pre;
            }
            length--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void remove(int data) {
if (isEmpty()) {
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
if (this.size == 1 && this.head.getData() == data) {
    this.head = this.tail = null;
    this.size--;
    return;
}
if (this.head.getData() == data) { 
    this.head = this.head.getNext();
    this.head.setPrevious(null);
    this.size--;
    return;
}
if (this.tail.getData() == data) { 
    this.tail = this.tail.getPrevious();
    this.tail.setNext(null);
    this.size--;
    return;
}

for (Node<T> current = this.head; current != null; current = current.getNext()) {
    if (current.getData() == data) {
        Node<T> previous = current.getPrevious();
        Node<T> next = current.getNext();
        previous.setNext(next);
        next.setPrevious(previous);
        this.size--;
        return;
    }
  }
  throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```